# Exit Select Case - VBA MsAccess

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, exit-code, select-case

I need to exit the select case in vba ms access but I cant figure how to do it, this is a screen shot of the error I get.

[image]

Comment: what's stopping you typing text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this won't work...

```vbs
Select Case Cat
    Case 1
        If (Condition1 Or Condition2 Or Condition3) Then
            Exit Select  ' <- Compile error
        End If

        ' do stuff
```

...then why not just do this instead?

```vbs
Select Case Cat
    Case 1
        If Not (Condition1 Or Condition2 Or Condition3) Then

            ' do stuff

        End If
```

Comment: This is what I did after all, thnx